# "Horizontal rule" section of help page

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

["Horizontal rule"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#horizontal-rules) section of help page contains hot key info in collapsed mode:

> [image: collapsed]

But it dissappears after pressing "show more" link:

> [image: expanded]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks fixed now:

> [image: fixed]