# Refresh instead of scroll

Tags: bug, android-app

When on [the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289147/339911) trying to scroll page leads to update request.

> [image: video]

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-H860
- OS Version: 6.0.1 (1634100298931)